# Angular Animation not transitioning in IE11 and Firefox (works in Chrome)

Tags: angular, typescript, cross-browser, angular-animations

My Angular animation attached to a div works in Chrome (increasing the a height of 0 to height: '*'). I have imported all the necessary polyfills and installed web-animations-js

The height increases, however there is no animation transition happening in IE and Firefox.

animations.ts

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  animate
} from "@angular/animations";

export const Animations = {
  animations: [
    trigger("expansionTrigger", [
      state(
        "true",
        style({
          height: "*",
          display: "inline-block",
          width: "100%",
          overflow: "hidden"
        })
      ),
      state(
        "false",
        style({
          height: "0",
          display: "none",
          padding: "0",
          overflow: "hidden"
        })
      ),
      transition("true => false", animate("1s 100ms ease-out")),
      transition("false => true", animate("1s ease-in"))
    ]),
    trigger("fadeInTrigger", [
      state(
        "true",
        style({
          opacity: "1"
        })
      ),
      state(
        "false",
        style({
          opacity: "0"
        })
      ),
      transition("true => false", animate("1s ease")),
      transition("false => true", animate("1s 300ms ease"))
    ])
  ]
};
```

content.component.html

```
<div
[@expansionTrigger]="isExpanded === 'true' ? 'true' : 'false'"
[@fadeInTrigger]="isExpanded === 'true' ? 'true' : 'false'"
class="ds-u-sans">
    <div class="padding-20">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

content.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Animations } from '../animations'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accordion-content',
  templateUrl: './accordion-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accordion-content.component.css'],
  animations: [
    Animations.animations
  ]
})
export class AccordionContentComponent  {
  isExpanded: string = "false";

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't know if you've found a solution yet or if this will actually help your particular situation, but I had a similar problem and fixed it by using explicit `marginTop` / `paddingBottom` / etc properties in my animations instead of shorthand `margin` / `padding` / etc.

[This comment on Angular Issue #16330](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16330#issuecomment-302171967) pointed me in this direction.

I know your problem is with `height`, but in your `"false"` state there is a shorthand `padding` property which makes me wonder if that is what Edge and Firefox are being hung up on.

For example, instead of:

```
state(
  "false",
  style({
    height: "0",
    display: "none",
    padding: "0",       <------
    overflow: "hidden"
  })
)
```

..maybe try:

```
state(
  "false",
  style({
    height: "0",
    display: "none",
    paddingTop: "0",    <------
    paddingBottom: "0", <------
    overflow: "hidden"
  })
)
```

Also, `display:none` can have odd, if any behaviour with animations. Transitions don't take place between `display: inline-block` and `display: none`, and the element [can be treated as if the initial state had never occurred and the element was always in its final state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#JavaScript_examples).

Perhaps instead of your states being `"true"` and `"false"`, you could use `'*'` and `'void'` with an `*ngIf` in your template if it makes sense for your application.

It may require some refactoring, but the *intention* behind `display:none` can sometimes be the same as `state('void')`. Then instead of letting the css decide what is present in the DOM, Angular is doing it with `void` and `*ngIf`, and you can avoid the css `display` behaviour all together.

[Angular 'void' state documentation.](https://angular.io/guide/animations#the-void-state)

[Additional 'void' clarification under Parameters > name.](https://angular.io/api/animations/state)

Sorry if this answer is a bit vague, but these points helped me solve similar issues. Hopefully they can point someone else in the right direction.

Comment: This saved me a ton of time, thank you, the problem still exists as of FF 64 and @angular/animations 7.2.0